# RouterLink shows hyperlink on screen (below) I don't want to show hyperLink on page

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-routerlink

`<a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a> can i remove hyperlink ?`

**when i use**

`<button routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>`

**it works like what i want**

but i want to add routerLinkOptions and it shows button error!
**my aim is to remove hyperlink from screeen when hovering on link**

Comment: If I got your intention correctly, The CSS trick will be `text-decoration: none`. 
In which case the following example will work for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fppcwh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component.css file, add the following CSS class,

```
.anchor-style {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 cursor: default !important;
}
```

In your component.html file, add the `anchor-style` class to your anchor HTML element.

```
<a class="anchor-style" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

If this does not answer to your query, you can try the following,

1. Apply the RouterLinkActive to an ancestor of a RouterLink.

   `<div routerLinkActive="active-link-styles" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <button routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</button>
      <button routerLink="/home">Home</button>
    </div>`

This will set the active-link-styles class on the div tag if the url is either '/dashboard' or '/home'.

2. You can call a function on the click event. Which in turns navigates to the desired screen.
   In component.html file, 
   `<button (click)="navigateToDashboard()">Dashboard</button>`
   In component.ts file, `navigateToDashboard() { this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']) }`

Comment: i also want that routerLink don't take me to dashboard page!

Comment: cursor not working cursor: default is not removing hyperlink i just want to hide my hyperlink

Comment: Every thing is working fine i did <div routerLink="\dashboard" routerLinkActive="rg-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{match:['/dashboardr']}" role="button> but now i need routerlink should not take me to that page on click

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. Do you mean that on click of the HTML div element, it should not route you to "/dashboard"??